# Can not s:HSlider in fx script

Tags: flex4

I am new in flex and my question may not be at your professional level but I would deeply appreciate any help. Thank you.

I am trying to use spark **HSlider** in the following code but compiler generates an error. I have to change **mx:HSlider** for code to be error free.
Will it be possible to use **s:HSlider** instead **mx:HSlider**?

Below is the sample functioning code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Style source="Arcade_Slider.css"/>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.SliderEvent;
        private var txtvalue:int = 0;
        protected function Focal_changeHandler(event:SliderEvent):void
        {
            txtvalue = Focal.value;
            if(txtvalue == 0)
                Slider_txt.text = "Low";
            if(txtvalue == 1)
                Slider_txt.text = "Middle";
            if(txtvalue == 2)
                Slider_txt.text = "High";

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:HSlider id="Focal" x="402" y="285" maximum="2" minimum="0" value="0" buttonMode="true" enabled="true" snapInterval="1" tickInterval="1" allowTrackClick="true" liveDragging="true" change="Focal_changeHandler(event)"/>
<s:Label id="Slider_txt" x="423" y="252" text= "Low"/>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Hi. I appreciate your prompt answer. Thank you very much for perfect and accurate response. Two Thumbs UP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your **HSlider** as below:

```
<s:HSlider id="Focal" x="402" y="285" maximum="2" minimum="0" value="0" buttonMode="true" enabled="true" snapInterval="1"  liveDragging="true" change="Focal_changeHandler(event)"/>
```

and use **Event** instead of **SliderEvent** in changeHandler line as below:

```
 protected function Focal_changeHandler(event:Event):void
```